# Cannot update java from 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: java, macos

As a part of "dbeaver" installation troubleshooting i am trying to update java on my mac from 1.6 to 1.7. I downloaded and installed latest java 8 available from oracle site ,but still java version remains the same.

I even tried  updating from java control panel from system preferences,issue remains the same.

can someone let me know why i am getting this issue?,below are the details.

```
| => java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)

| /usr/bin @boston 
| => sw_Vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.6
BuildVersion:   15G31
```

Comment: Where do you need java 1.7 for? In what application are you using it?

Comment: i want to use "dbeaver" application.

    | => ls -tlr | head -2
    total 32
    lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   52 Feb 15 13:16 CurrentJDK ->    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents

    | => pwd
    /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions

even i see the current version is linked to older version 1.6

Answer (score 4):

Open a terminal and type `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)`

Answer (score 0):

Open the `.bash_profile`

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

add following line

```
export  JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

This tells your `/usr/bin/java` link target to use the latest Java 7 Package installed in

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
```

So for `JDK 1.7.0_17` **JAVA_HOME** would be:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Ho
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install the full JDK (Java Development Kit). You only updated the JRE (Java Runtime Environment).